# Template alias for another alias

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have some problem with 'using' keyword in c++11.
This piece of code should create alias for pointer to another type.

```
template <typename T>
class SomeClass
{
    typedef typename std::add_pointer<T>::type pointer;

    template <typename U>
    using rebind_pointer = typename std::pointer_traits<pointer>::rebind<U>;
}

SomeClass<int> obj;
```

But in gcc 4.7 I've got compile error:

> `typename std::pointer_traits<int*>::rebind` names `template<class _Up> using rebind = _Up*`, which is not a type

I found out that pointer_traits::rebind is a template alias itself so maybe that is problem ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler to parse `rebind` as a template:

```
template <typename U>
using rebind_pointer = typename std::pointer_traits<pointer>::template rebind<U>;
//                                                            ^^^^^^^^
```

This is necessary because `std::pointer_traits<pointer>` is dependent on a template parameter (`T`).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more details about when and why you need to use the `template` keyword.